# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when i set UILabel title in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, exc-bad-instruction

I want to change the title of an UILabel, but I receive an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.
My label was correctly connected to the storyboard and I don't understand why i have an error. 
Could anybody please point where I am wrong? Thank you for your help.

There is my code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.numberLabel.text = "qwerty" // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode0x0)
    }
}
```

Comment: is it linked against Interface Builder?

Comment: Maybe you want to say `self.numberLabel.text = "qwerty"`?

Comment: Sorry, in my code, it's not self.label, but it's self.numberLabel

Comment: ^^so you really should copy&paste real code that has a problem, and not re-write it. if you re-write your program, it will probably just work ;)

Comment: Sometimes the connections between IB and code can get broken (e.g. when you rename stuff). Have you tried deleting the outlet reference in IB and then readding it?

Comment: I have tried to delete and readding, but I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved my problem.
Strangely, if I reinstall Xcode, It's work.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

the problem can be localization. Check if you have 2 storyboards created (one base for english and second for other languages). Then check if in both you have the same label. If not it can be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should write `self.numberLabel.text = "Your text"` instead of       `self.label.text = "Your text"` because you have outlet named numberLabel not label .